# React-Select isMulti retrieve selected options

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm currently working on a springboot/reactjs project. I'm using the react select library to set a multi select input in one of my forms but I could not get the selected values here's some code to make it a bit clearer.
[these are my options generated dynamically from the database each option has the webService Id as a value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN7qS.png)

[this is my select input, I need to get the selected values "Ids" and then call the method that retrieves the webservices from the database and then assign the list of webServices to my newApplicationData.webservices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpGHK.png)

[this is the get web service function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3PHn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update : I kind off found a solution to my problem :  on the onChange prop I used this

```
     onChange={(selectedOptions) => {
                const state = this.state;
                state.selectedWebServices = [];
                selectedOptions.forEach((option) => {
                  this.getWS(option.value);
                  state.selectedWebServices.push(this.state.getWSData);
                });
                state.newApplicationData.webServices =
                  state.selectedWebServices;
                this.setState(state);
              }}
```

and then I found out another problem: even if I select two deffrent options the list of selected options only gets one duplicated option????!!!!